# Docker-compose logs are only showing "Attaching to" and nothing else

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

After running  `"docker-compose up -d --force-recreate " + service_name` via a python `subprocess.call()`, I then afterwards want to print out the logs from the docker-compose command using just a simple `"docker-compose logs " + service_name`. However, the logs will randomly only have "Attaching to" in them, rather than the full printout of logs. I am doing database changes to the containers, with first DDL changes and then DML changes. It turns out that the container is successfully being spun up and my changes made, and when I go to run the DML stage the container successfully upgrades and logs will print out, so it seems that the logs are getting stuck at "Attaching to" even though the container is continuing on to complete.

Why would docker-compose logs only be showing "Attaching to"?

Part of docker-compose file:

```yaml
services:
  #
  # Components
  # ----------
  #
  agile:
    image: image
    ports:
    - 10031:8080
    environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx768m -Xss512k
    - ACTIVE_RELEASE_ID=${ACTIVE_RELEASE_ID}
    - CACHE_HOST=localdocker
    - CODE_DROP_ID=${CODE_DROP_ID}
    - ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=side
    - EUREKA_HOST=localdocker
    - KV_STORE_ADDRESS=localdocker:8500
    - KV_STORE_HOST=localdocker
    - KV_STORE_PORT=8500
    - KV_STORE_TYPE=remote
    - MESSAGING_HOST=localdocker
    - SEARCH_HOST=localdocker
    - SPRING_CLOUD_CONSUL_CONFIG_ENABLED=true
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=localdocker
    extra_hosts:
    - localdocker:${LOCALDOCKER_HOSTNAME}
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        tag: docker
        env: NodeHostName,NodeID,Service,ServiceLabels,Task,TaskSlot,TaskID,TZ
        fluentd-address: ${LOCALDOCKER_HOSTNAME}:24224
        fluentd-async-connect: "true"
```

That is one of roughly 40 components that are being built. I am using Ansible to do asynchronous running of my commands.

Comment: Add a minimal `docker-compose.yaml`, `python script` please.

Comment: I added part of the `docker-compose` file. The python is me just running a subprocess.call on the above docker up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Attaching to the container(which name of that is give  in the compose file) from the image which is built through the docker-file. there is a error with container and images by the way of mismatched the  details as names of containers and images  while in UP ...

Comment: So are you saying that the issue of why the `docker-compose logs` only shows "Attaching to" is because there is a name mismatch occurring during the UP command?

Comment: yeah. i learned this from that faced issues while UP the compose file

Answer (score 11):

My problem when facing a blank `Attaching to` message:

Since I had started the app with
`docker-compose -p my-fancy-name up -d`,
to receive the logs for this, I also had to pass the same `-p` flag:

`docker-compose -p my-fancy-name logs -f`

Comment: I did not have the same setup as yours, but running my docker-compose stack with -p directive and logging with -p did solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - in my case, the problem was simply solved by `cd` into the directory where the docker-compose file is. Then `docker-compose logs -f` again.

Comment: yep this was it. I was in the wrong folder the entire time