# Docker doesn't show file logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-logs

I'm trying to show Docker logs from Terminal, however all it's showing me is "`Attaching to`" and that's it.

No logs and no other stuff. I'm running a Mac OS X (Mojave); I've build the container from the image, however no logs are to be seen.

What could I've done wrong? What does this "`Attaching to`" mean?

```
> MacBook:ubuntu-ccit bini$ docker-compose logs -f   
> Attaching to  
> MacBook:ubuntu-ccit bini$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose logs are only showing "Attaching to" and nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512624/docker-compose-logs-are-only-showing-attaching-to-and-nothing-else)

Comment: We prefer cut & paste text rather than embedded images. You'll get less help with images.

Comment: @AdamP I did check that answer much earlier before posting this question, however it still isn't showing any logs.